# MATLAB: Imagesc and scaling all images to use one scale

Tags: matlab, image-scaling

I am using imagesc in a loop to create 100 images. As far as I'm aware, the colour scale is individual in each image.

**So my first question is...does each image have a different scale?**

(my results would indicate this but I need clarification)

result is a 7x7xt matrix.

Part of the loop showing this is...

```
 t=100;

 for j=1:t
     figure;
     imagesc(result(:,:,j));
     filename = sprintf('model.png', j);
 end
```

**My second question is...if they do have different scales, is there a simple way to make them all use the same appropriate scale?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1:** Yes.

**Question 2:**

If you read the [manual page](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/imagesc.html), you'll see it says:

> `imagesc(...,clims)` normalizes the values in `C` to the range specified by `clims` and displays `C` as an image. `clims` is a two-element vector that limits the range of data values in `C`. These values map to the full range of values in the current colormap.

Comment: I must have originally read that wrong as I have been using the manual page. I must give that a go. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can also change the color limits outside of IMAGESC with [CAXIS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/caxis.html) function.

```
for j=1:t
    %# ...
    imagesc(result(:,:,j));
    if j==1
        cl = caxis; %# get color limits from the 1st image
    else
        caxis(cl) %# apply the same color limits to other images
    end
    %# ...
end
```

Comment: Brilliant, exactly what I wanted! Thanks!